# Can you change the background and/or foreground colors of an SWT TabItem?

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to change the background and/or foreground colors of the text on an SWT TabItem; however, it (and it's class hierarchy) don't seem to have methods for this - and I can't seem to find any other members I can get ahold of to do this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this isn't supported (at least not today) in the TabItem/TabFolder featureset:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=96239

It also turns out that it is not supported in the CTabItem/CTabFolder featureset:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=75411

bummer.

Comment: oops that is rather surprising. Too late to change to something else for GUI stuff?